# splunk and how to do alerting on the first/last business day

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Splunk cron job does not provide a way for running scheduled queries on last and first business days of a month.

In that case I need to provide the data in the query and pass it to alerting condition.

For example:
I need to check each last business day if a file has been delivered. So an ideal alerting condition is:
`count < 1 AND is_last_business_day=1`

Here I need to check if the query was executed on the last business day.

I wonder if someone can help with a query to check if it is the last business day and pass it as a field. So it can be used in alert conditions.

Comment: If you have not seen it already, have a look: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Alerting/How-to-configure-a-cron-schedule-for-an-alert-to-run-on-the-last/m-p/215177.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things and also using some parts of the query from Daniel here is my solution.

I think this can be improved and may become a shorter query. I tried to write a query that is not the shortest but easy to understand.

The `| stats count` in the beginning is just to give eval values in the query output even without any results. So you can test the query without any additional conditions or waiting for some dataset results.

I have tested this query with multiple dates and it is working.

````
| stats count 
| eval mydate=strptime("07/28/2022", "%m/%d/%Y")
| eval today_weekday=strftime(mydate,"%w") 
| eval today_number=strftime(mydate,"%d") 
| eval is_today_business_day=if(today_weekday>=1 and today_weekday<=5,1,0) 
``` caluclate last day of month ```
| eval last_day_number=strftime(relative_time(now(),"@month-1d"),"%d")
``` tomorrow for checking if it is a business day ```
| eval tomorrow=relative_time(mydate,"+1d@d") 
| eval tomorrow_day=strftime(tomorrow,"%w") 
| eval tomorrow_number =strftime(tomorrow,"%d") 
| eval is_tomorrow_business_day=if(tomorrow_day>=1 and tomorrow_day<=5,1,0) 
| eval is_tomorrow_day_one=if(tomorrow_number=1,1,0) 
| eval is_today_in_last_3days=if(today_number>last_day_number-3,1,0)
``` is today a business day AND is today in the last 3 days of month and ( is tomorrow not a businessday OR is tomorrow day one of next month ```
| eval is_today_last_business_day=if(is_today_business_day=1 and is_today_in_last_3days=1 and (is_tomorrow_business_day!=1 OR is_tomorrow_day_one=1),1,0)
````

Answer (score 1):

```
| eval Date=now(),dayofmonth=strftime(Date,"%d"),weekday=strftime(Date,"%w"),lastDayOfMonth=strftime(relative_time(now(),"@month-1d"),"%d")
| eval is_last_business_day=case(lastDayOfMonth-dayofmonth<7 AND (weekday IN(1,2,3,4,5)),1,True(),0)
```

Using this statement would work.
it adds the fields Date,dayofmonth,weekday and lastDayOfMonth.
then uses these to calculate if its a last BusinessDay.

Which in this I have defined as the last weekday in the month.

You can stack eval statements by separating them with commas, feel free to put this all in one line or split them up for readability

Comment: thanks for the reply Daniel I checked the query and it gives true for multiple days. For example, it gives True for the 25,26,27,28,29th of July.

Comment: Your right, Originally i was only checking for the last friday of the month, i changed this because this wouldn't be the last weekday of the month, the change i made i didn't think about its impact

Answer (score 0):

```
| eval Date=now(),dayofmonth=strftime(Date,"%d"),weekday=strftime(Date,"%w"),lastDayOfMonth=strftime(relative_time(now(),"@month-1d"),"%d")
| eval daystillend=lastDayOfMonth-dayofmonth, daystillnextweekday=case(weekday=5,2,True(),0)
| eval is_last_business_day=case(DaysTillEOM<=DaysTillNextWeekDay AND (weekday IN(1,2,3,4,5)),1,True(),0)
```

New Answer to this question to fix the old one's issues

Approach is get number of days till end of month, and number of days till next weekday
We compare the number of days till end of month and days till next weekday to see if this is the last weekday before end of month (filtering out saturday and sunday too)